# What is the true shape of a black hole?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, event-horizon, kerr-metric

I’m pretty sure if a black hole is rotating, then it is shaped as an oblate spheroid. But I know that the equations of general relativity tell that instead of having just one radius. In location of the event horizon, there are two radii. So I don’t know whether it is a flat disk or rather an oblate spheroid.

Comment: You're asking about the shape of a rotating black hole's event horizon?  Such an object has an inner horizon and an outer horizon, as well as a region called the *ergosphere*.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_black_hole

Comment: I am terribly sorry about that I should have specifically stated which of these I was asking about. What is the shape of event horizon on the inside. For a deeper understanding and a helpful visual aid.

Comment: In a very real sense the shape of a black hole is the spacetime metric rather than any horizons. The latter may be more visible, but they are not the black hole itself.